# Return HTML (including images) via Json ASP .NET MVC4

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I return a Partial view result to view by using Ajax and Json, I am working in ASP .NET MVC4 structure. The html also include images. here I am using code to return data that is not working properly.

```
return PartialView("_OnlineUsers", online_users);
```

Can I return data in form of HTML(including images) through json???

Answer (score 0):

Write your ajax call like this

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: { id: "ID" },
        success: function(result){
            $('.divContent').html(result);
        } 
    });
});
```

on your controller

```
public PartialViewResult Action(int id){
    var online_users = //populate your model
    return PartialView("_OnlineUsers", online_users);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't return html and json with same ajax request.Another way to get the partial view is

```
$.get('@Url.Action("yourActionName","YOurControllerNme")',function(data){
$('#YourDivId').html(data);
});
```

There is nothing wrong in your server side code

To get the Image you may use

```
<div class="display-field">
        <img src="@Url.Action("getPhotoAction", "ControllerName", new { id = Model.Id })" 
             title="@Model.TitleYouWantToSer"/>
    </div>
```